# Alertmanager default receiver:null is not replacing with the routes specified

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using prometheus-operator to create alertmanager setup. Prometheus-Alertmanager integration is working fine, I am able to see the alerts in alertmanager. But the alert is receiving in default null receiver other than the specific one.
Below is my AlertmanagerConfig spec

```html
spec:
  route:
    groupBy:
      - severity
    groupInterval: 5m
    groupWait: 30s
    receiver: OpsGenie
    repeatInterval: 15h
    routes:
      - continue: true
        matchers:
          - name: severity
            value: critical
        receiver: OpsGenie
  receivers:
    - name: OpsGenie
      opsgenieConfigs:
        - apiKey:
            key: apikey
            name: opsgenie-creds
          apiURL: https://*.app.opsgenie.com/
          priority: P1
          responders:
            - name: Eteam
              type: team
          sendResolved: true
```

But the rendered configuration i am able to see in the alertmanager UI is below:

```html
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  http_config:
    follow_redirects: true
  smtp_hello: localhost
  smtp_require_tls: true
  pagerduty_url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
  opsgenie_api_url: https://api.opsgenie.com/
  wechat_api_url: https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/
  victorops_api_url: https://alert.victorops.com/integrations/generic/20131114/alert/
  telegram_api_url: https://api.telegram.org
route:
  receiver: "null"
  continue: false
  routes:
  - receiver: manu-john/infra-monitoring/OpsGenie
    group_by:
    - severity
    matchers:
    - namespace="manu-john"
    continue: true
    routes:
    - receiver: manu-john/infra-monitoring/OpsGenie
      match:
        severity: critical
      continue: true
    group_wait: 30s
    group_interval: 5m
    repeat_interval: 15h
receivers:
- name: "null"
- name: manu-john/infra-monitoring/OpsGenie
  opsgenie_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    http_config:
      follow_redirects: true
    api_key: <secret>
    api_url: https://*.app.opsgenie.com/
    message: '{{ template "opsgenie.default.message" . }}'
    description: '{{ template "opsgenie.default.description" . }}'
    source: '{{ template "opsgenie.default.source" . }}'
    responders:
    - name: Eteam
      type: team
    priority: P1
templates: []
```

Below are the Alerts showing in Alertmanager, only visible in null receiver, but my expectation in Opsgenie receiver
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you set a continue true under spec.route. I see you already have it under spec.route.routes